# Time-dependent coxph output and making predictions in R

Tags: r, prediction, cox-model, hazard, time-varying-covariate

I'm trying to use a Cox proportional hazard model to predict the time until an employee terminates from an organization.  There are a bunch of covariates (~20), some of them time-dependent.  So I've structured my data appropriately, created a survival object, and fed it to the coxph function successfully.  Abbreviated code sample:

```
surv1 = Surv(Interval.Start, Interval.End, Is.Term.Record)
fit1 = coxph(surv1 ~ Age + Tenure + Gender + Stock + Perf, data=mydata)
```

I have a limited understanding of semi-parametric models and I'm a beginner in R, so I understand the coef and stats output but I don't know how to use `fit1` to make predictions given data on a current employee despite reading some of the other posts on this topic.  Should I be using something like

```
predict(fit1,newdata=covs,type="expected")
```

...but in that case, what should `covs` look like?  And what will the output be--the expected time-to-termination or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should be using that sort of call. You need to provide a set of covariates that match both the original set as well as covering the time intervals of interest for the prediction. See `?predict.coxph` and you may also need `?survfit.coxph`

Comment: You may also need `?survfit.coxph`. Unless you have `attach`-ed the dataset, your creation of the `Surv()` object will not have succeeded. Therneau specifically warns against creating Surv-objects outside of the 'coxph' function because of later difficulties with the environments not being correctly accessible.

Comment: I actually did nest `Surv()` inside `coxph()` in my original code.  I changed it in my post for aesthetics, but you're right, I should've been more careful.  My mistake.  Also, after reading `?predict.coxph` several times, I still don't understand exactly what the `newdata` argument should look like when making a new prediction.  I'm also not sure what you mean by "a set of covariates that match the original set as well as covering the time intervals of interest for the prediction".  Can you provide an example table?  Thanks for your responses...I've been struggling with this for days!

Comment: I don't understand why I should be expected to create an example when you have not yet provided one.

Comment: Fair enough...the code [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h37ms4C7fU6V9VIHU-y9O0UloAazzYcPO_Yk6HnhXk4), the model training data [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ShRKGMoxi7yNsn5wucV0hVs8lvLIYQSlLF2esITSTwA), and the data for the employee of interest [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vg2rxxybbqzP2R0Hcy09dkpGIYAenKBQbmkrhJ3I8oc). The first 6 rows of data for the employee of interest are intended to be the employee's history up to the current day. After this the data is forward looking and is simply forecast with everything staying constant except for age, which is predictable

Comment: @Fist Pump Cat: Were you able to figure out how to predict the future for the right-censored observations without knowing the values of the time-varying co-variates. Sorry I am unable to make this a comment

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `rms` package. 
I extracted codes from the relevant posts ([Predicting Cox survival with time-dependent covariates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296358/predicting-cox-survival-with-time-dependent-covariates/394537#394537)):

```
vfit2 <- cph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno*strat(tgroup), data=vet2,surv = T,x=T,y=T)
prob = survest(vfit2,newdata=vet2[vet2$id==2,],times=210)$surv
```